# Selecting single element of a div class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of links in a header and I want to use jQuery to select a single one of those links and `animate()` over it. Here is my HTML:

`<div id="header_links">
        <div class="header_link"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
        <div class="header_link"><a href="/aboutme">About Me</a></div>
        <div class="header_link"><a href="/resume">Resume</a></div>
        <div class="header_link"><a href="/contact">Contact Me</a></div>
</div>`

and here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
     * Perform actions on header links:
     */
    var header_link = $('.header_link');

    header_link.bind('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate(
            {
                height: '2.5em'
            }
        );

    });

    header_link.bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate(
            {
                height: '2em'
            }
        );
    });

});
```

To be clear -- I want to be able to mouse over a link, increase its height to 2.5em, then put its height back at 2em after the mouse leaves the link. As is, all of the links are getting bigger and smaller.

I apologize if this is a repeat of another question -- I looked through other similar questions and was having no luck in finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: It is increasing the height of all of the elements link <div>'s instead of just the one the mouse is hovering over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should the height in mouseleave be `1em` instead of `2em` ?

working fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/C7dYV/